# Why does VIM change the columns variable after Ctrl+z? (Setting the width of text in the VIM editor)

Tags: bash, macos

I start up vim using the following command:
`vim -u NONE -U NONE -c ':set columns=40 nu'`

[image]

Then, I push `vim` to the foreground...

[image]

...and return.

[image]

For some reason, VIM has changed the columns variable to the width of the window without me telling it to do that.

Note that I did not manually resize the window after Ctrl+Z.

The reason that I tried to change the `:columns` value was to *change the width of the VIM editor*. If the `:columns` variable is not the right solution, could you provide some better ideas for changing the width?

Comment: is there a reason, why you did set columns to an obviously wrong value?

Comment: When? After returning to foreground? Vim set it to 69 automatically somehow

Comment: Yes and this is probably the correct terminal size. So let me ask you again, why do you need tell vim a different terminal size? This is going to cause subtle strange behaviour

Comment: The goal was to have line wrapping at a page width of 40, regardless of the terminal sizr

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166789) ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker is correct. You probably want to check out the 'textwidth' option

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Feel free to critique my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:columns` is an internal VIM property that is intended to be a mirror for the number of columns for the *interactive shell environment* that VIM is running under.

`:columns` should always match the result of `tput cols` (for bash). This means that VIM is able to automatically reflow the text on the screen when the terminal dimensions change. One such reflow event is triggered when VIM recovered from a "STOPPED" (ctrl+Z) state.

`:columns` is not the best way to set the width of text in the VIM editor. In most GUI environments, simply resizing the VIM window is the best way

**Recommendation**

- Windowed GUI environments: Simply click and drag the terminal to the desired size.
- Plain console: (BASH) Run `stty cols ${COLUMN_WIDTH}` in the shell to set the number of columns for your terminal. This will change the dimensions of your shell, and VIM will automatically pick up the new dimensions.